# Saving the predicted values of a classifier into an excel spreadsheet, python scklearn

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

Using sklearn I have predicted the values. I want to save these predicted values onto a new excel file along with their unique ID.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier as ABC
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier as DTC
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RFC
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# Initialize the models

#adaboostclassifier
clf_A = ABC(random_state = 1)
 clf_A.fit(X_train,y_train)
pred_A=clf_A.predict(X_test)
```

I want to store the pred_A and the ['SSL'] in the Xtrain file to a new csv file. Any suggestions on how I can do this.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you already searched for a solution using Google/Stack Overflow, and if so what have you found? Also what is ['SSL']? A column from your training set? Why would you want to store a column from training alongside the predictions for the test set?

Comment: @mihai The thing is the testSet does not have the attribute output of the classifier I predicted inside it. I need to output the values I predicted to the testSet which is another csv file. I have no idea why they did it like this. But this is what it is. I have searched almost everywhere ,but could not find it.

Comment: Okay, why not just append the predictions to the test set and then write that to a CSV then?

Comment: I tried it, but It gives me errors. 

predictions=clf_A.predict(data_test)

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/shadmanspc/Documents/testingSet2.csv")

for i in range(0,len(predictions)):
    df['QUALIFIED'][i] = predictions[i]
df.to_csv("testingSet6.csv", index=False)

Comment: Don't post code in commends, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52770167/edit) instead. If you've already tried and have a specific problem you encountered, such as an exception that got thrown, then also include the **full** traceback so others can see how far you've gotten and specifically what it is you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simplest way is something like this:

```
clf_A = ABC(random_state = 1)
clf_A.fit(X_train, y_train)

pred_A = clf_A.predict(X_test)

resultingDF = pd.DataFrame()# you create new dataframe
resultingDF['predictions'] = pred_A# you create column with values
resultingDF['SSL'] = ...
```

I suppose, you take SSL values from X_test. So if your X_test is pandas dataframe it will be:

```
resultingDF['SSL'] = X_test['SSL'].values
```

If your X_test is already 2D array, you use index (to get column) (#1) or you save (earlier) SSL column from there somewhere and use it now (#2) or you take X_test and make from it dataframe again and then go code above (this is #3).